# app created through expo-cli crashing on ios real device

Tags: ios, react-native, crash, react-native-ios, expo

After I executed 'xattr -cr path/to/your.app' command ,app got installed in simulator. but its crashing in the real device.

crash report:

```
error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 
"Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.aq.FOGVERSION2"
 UserInfo={
NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.aq.FOGVERSION2,
 BKSProcessExitReason=0, 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job,
 NSUnderlyingError=0x282299320 
{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 
"No such process" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The process failed to exec, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Consult /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log 
for more information, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get valid task name port right for pid 2019}},
 `BSErrorCodeDescription`=bootstrap-failed}
```

can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Did you enter a bundle identifier in Xcode?

Comment: I am using expo-cli, so expo is taking care of everything.

Comment: Even provisioning profiles?